# Adding a line of random numbers together and at the end of the line printing the total

Tags: python, random

import random
import time

RollAgain = "yes"

while RollAgain == "yes" or RollAgain == "y":

```
DiceThrows = int(input('How many Dice would you like to throw: '))
DiceType = int(input ('How many sides are on your dice: '))
throw = 0

print 'Rolling the Dice...'
for throw in range (DiceThrows):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(random.randint(1,DiceType)), # Comma prints number on same line
                                       How do you add them on the same line?
RollAgain = raw_input("Would you like to roll again? ")
```

Comment: Append them all to a list and use `sum()` after

Comment: You mean print in same line? Python3 or Python2?

Comment: Python 2, on the same line if it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems like your formatting is not correct. On the other hand please provide some context to your code. Maybe describe what it is doing in a few words and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`.

```
import random 
import time
import sys
RollAgain = "yes"

while   RollAgain == "yes" or RollAgain == "y":

  DiceThrows = int(input('How many Dice would you like to throw: '))
  DiceType = int(input ('How many sides are on your dice: '))
  throw = 0

  print('Rolling the Dice...')
  sum = 0
  for throw in range (DiceThrows):
      time.sleep(1)
      no = random.randint(1,DiceType)
      sum += no
      sys.stdout.write(str(no) + " ")
  print("= %d" %sum)
  RollAgain = raw_input("Would you like to roll again? ")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very nooby at this...
How many Dice would you like to throw: 5
How many sides are on your dice: 20
Rolling the Dice...
2 20 11 6 13 = 52?

Comment: Oh you want sum as well!

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Awwww it looks like it should work but maybe I put it in wrong. The summed number at the end is just the last number in the random generation... Sorry if I'm wasting time here, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry! I missed the "sum = 0" piece! Its works great, thank you!